# why is boolean returning True through this.props in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a file, check.js, for my nav to check if the name is not set, it should show the `addNameScreen` and `phoneNumberScreen` components but when I use the props to get the value of the boolean it returns true but I need this to be false so that when the users add their name it changes the value to true in check.js.

My question is: how the hell is it returning the value true? and how would I be able to return the value to change the state in check.js when the user has added the name?

**Check.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MainNav from './MainNav';
import addNameScreen from '../screens/auth/addNameScreen';
import PhoneNumberScreen from '../screens/auth/PhoneNumberScreen';


export default class Check extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        isNameSet: false, 
        isPhoneNumberSet: false,
     }
  }

render(){

     if(this.state.isNameSet == false){
        return <AddNameScreen isNameSet />
     }else if(this.state.isPhoneNumberSet == false){
         return <PhoneNumberScreen isPhoneNumberSet/>
     }else{
        return <MainNav />
     }
}  
}

export {Check};
```

**AddNameScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Alert, Image, 
KeyboardAvoidingView, Button} from 'react-native';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {Input} from './../../components/input'; 
import MainScreen from '../MainScreen';
import PhoneNumberScreen from './PhoneNumberScreen';

export default class AddNameScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        currentUser: '', 
        Name: '',
        error: '',
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.setState({ currentUser })

    if (currentUser != null) {
        email = currentUser.email;
    }

}

addName = () => {

    if(this.state.Name != ""){
        var Name = this.state.Name;

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(currentUser) {
            if (currentUser) {
              // User is signed in.
              firebase.database().ref('users/'+uid).set(
                {
                   Name: Name,
                   email: email,
                }
                ).then(() =>{ // name has been added.
                    this.updateName;
                    return <Check/>
                }).catch((error) => {
                    Alert.alert('Unknown error!');
                });
            } else {
              // User is signed out.
              // ...
            }
          });

    }else{
        this.setState({ error: 'Please enter your name!' }, () => {
            this.state.error; 
        });
    }
}
render(){

    return (
        <View style={[ styles.container, {flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgb(75, 2, 112)',}]}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Input 
                            placeholder='Enter your name'
                            placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
                            label='Enter your name?'
                            onChangeText={Name => this.setState({Name})}
                            value={this.state.Name}
                    />

                    <Button
                        title="Next"
                        color="#fff"
                        accessibilityLabel="Next"
                        onPress={this.addName}
                    /> 
                    <Text>{String(this.props.isNameSet)}</Text> //this print true
                    <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
export {AddNameScreen};
```

Comment: `return <AddNameScreen isNameSet />` is `===` to `return <AddNameScreen isNameSet={true} />`. What you want to do is `return <AddNameScreen isNameSet={this.state.isNameSet} />`

Comment: Don't use `== false` or `== true` to check the truth value of an expression. This behaves in a way which is almost certainly not what you want. Either use `===` or just check the expression directly inside the `if` - `if (expression)` evaluates the following block if and only if `expression` is truthy.

Comment: Thank you ! That now makes sense, i feel like an idiot haha, do you know how i would be able to change the value in isNameSet in checks.js when the user adds the name so it sets the state true and returns to check.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the question. I see in your code you are declaring props like so in Check.js

```
<MyComponent somePropName />
```

This by default sets somePropName to be true you should be setting the prop to a value (by using your state) like so:

```
<AddNameScreen isNameSet={this.state.isNameSet} />
```

To pass values back when you need to update state in the parent component, such as passing values from  back to  you need to use a callback function that you can invoke from .

This is done like the following:

```
<AddNameScreen isNameSet={this.state.isNameSet} updateName={this.updateName} />
```

Where updateName should be a function in your Check that updates its state such as:

```
updateName = (name) => {
    this.setState({isNameSet: true})
}
```

This function can then be used in the AddNameScreen by calling the props value through this.props.updateName().

The React documentation has a much better explanation on how to do this commonly called 'state hoisting' of 'lifting state up' and can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Jacob.

Comment: Thank You! Your answer has helped me! as i have been struggling to understand how to pass a state back to the parent! Would You know how i Could Return back to <Check /> on AddNameScreen so it could check if the phone number is true/>

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking for, but the easiest way for the AddNameScreen component to see if the this.state.isPhoneNumber value is true is by passing this value into AddNameScreen as a prob just like you do for isNameSet.

Comment: I have edited my code to show you what i mean. in addNameScreen.js it is in the function addName when the name has been added to the db. it should return to check.js

Comment: Yes as I thought, please see the link I provided regarding lifting up state from the react docs. That is a the best place to start and gives a very clear examples and guidance which you can build on.